# WooCommerce pages showing as blank

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-shortcode

The cart, my-account and checkout pages are all blank when I try view them. All I get is the header and footer. All I have done so far is download WooCommerce, go through the settings and add theme support. My shop page wasn't working until I added theme support but now thats the only page that does. Also I've noticed that if I use WooCommerce shortcode in my php files I can get the pages. But the shortcode doesn't seem to be working in the backend. BTW I'm using my own custom theme incase thats relevant.

What can I do to fix this?

update:
This must be an issue with my theme as if I set one of the default ones to active all the WooCommerce pages show. But I don't know what my themes issue is yet.

update: I have noticed that the WooCommerce pages are allowing me to add templates to them, apart from the shop page which is working. Why is this happening? 
[image]

Comment: First check if all shortcodes are placed correctly: https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/pages-not-displaying/
Second, turn on debugging, set WP_DEBUG to true in wp-config.php and see what prevents shortcodes from being rendered

Comment: I checked and the shortcodes are as they should be. I set WP_DEBUG to true and  I see no errors

Comment: You should switch to your theme back then, and view source of some page with issue. Also, check in console for JS errors. There might be some closing html tag missing. @Reece

Comment: I see no errors in the console or missing tags in the source.

Comment: Ok, then look for default page template in your theme and compare it with one of default themes. See if there is some template part missing, or modified, like content.php or content-page.php, etc @Reece

Comment: When you say default page template which page would that be? index.php? @niklaz

Comment: @niklaz I was missing the_content(); in my index.php file. Post it as an answer and I will give you credit. thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are few steps to do.

First turn on debug, by switching `WP_DEBUG` to true.

View source of page, and check if everything is being rendered, and also check console for JS error.

At last, for theme, if after switching to default theme, content shows up, there is a theme related issue.

Check for missing templates or template parts or structure within related with page from which content is missing and compare it with default themes templates and template parts.

See if there is some template part missing, or modified, like `content.php or content-page.php, the_content()` , etc.